# Enable debug logging for just one sub logger (via config, not code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I use the Python logging module in a rather "default" setup: Configuration happens via config file in the ini format and using `logging.config.fileConfig`. Logger names are the module names, so I have loggers called like this:

```
myapp.submoduleA
myapp.submoduleB
myapp.submoduleB
externalLibA
externalLibB
```

In my default setup, I set the log level of `myapp` to `INFO` and for `externalLibA` and `externalLibB`to `WARN`. But now I want to enable `DEBUG` for `myapp.submoduleB` only. Is there a simple way to do this, without writing code and by not explicitly configuring all other sub handlers?

The only options I currently see is to not configure a level for `myapp`, configure `DEBUG` for `myapp.submoduleB` and then manually configure `INFO` for all other sub handlers. As I have more than three of them in real life, this would be annoying and I wonder how other people handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you leave logger `myapp` at level `INFO` and just set logger `myapp.submoduleB` to level `DEBUG`, this should work as expected - `myapp` and `myapp.submoduleX` will be at `INFO` except for `myapp.submoduleB` which will be at `DEBUG`. Make sure you ensure `disable_existing_loggers` to `False` when calling `fileConfig()`.